# jQuery count child divs

Tags: jquery, count, numbers, custom-data-attribute

```
<ul>
    <li class="title" data-count="1" data-time="9000" data-title="unicorn">
    <li class="title" data-count="2" data-time="2000" data-title="giraffe">
    <li class="title" data-count="3" data-time="3000" data-title="dog">
    <li class="title" data-count="4" data-time="7000" data-title="cat">
    <li class="title" data-count="5" data-time="1000" data-title="dinosaur">
</ul>
```

As you can see the `data-count="/"` is just a counter. Do you have any ideas to automate this with jQuery, I haven't any ideas. Thanks for answers guys.

I think a variable could work with something like this:

```
var DivCount = X
$('.title').attr('data-count', DivCount);
```

PS: I don't ask only for free code, suggestions are welcome!

Comment: you can get child length using `$("ul > li").length`

Comment: Could you make use of [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var a = $("ul li");

jQuery.each(a, function(i, v) {
  $(v).attr("data-count", i + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="title" data-time="9000" data-title="unicorn">A</li>
    <li class="title" data-time="2000" data-title="giraffe">B</li>
    <li class="title" data-time="3000" data-title="dog">C</li>
    <li class="title" data-time="7000" data-title="cat">D</li>
    <li class="title" data-time="1000" data-title="dinosaur">E</li>
</ul>
```

Documentation for [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

Clean one...

```
for(var i = 1; i <= $('.title').length; i++) {
    $('.title').attr('data-count', i);
}
```

... another one...

```
$('.title').each(function(i, element) {
    $(element).attr('data-count', i + 1);
});
```

Pay attention on using node names as selectors, in case you have other lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lenght](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/prop_length.asp) propertie to count how many elements there are inside a div:

```js
console.log($("ul > li.title").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="title" data-count="1" data-time="9000" data-title="unicorn">
    <li class="title" data-count="2" data-time="2000" data-title="giraffe">
    <li class="title" data-count="3" data-time="3000" data-title="dog">
    <li class="title" data-count="4" data-time="7000" data-title="cat">
    <li class="title" data-count="5" data-time="1000" data-title="dinosaur">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly check

```
$('li.title').length
```

It will give you li with class 'title' count